# Finding the minimum number of transaction

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

The problem,

> There are $1024$ people. Each person is having $1024$ similar fruits. No
>   two persons are having same kind of fruits. Find the minimum number of
>   transactions required so that each-person is having $1024$ different
>   kinds offruits. Note that a single transaction is defined as exchange
>   of any number of fruits between any two persons.

The suggested solution is as follows:

> If $2$ people having $2$ fruits each then only one transaction will be
>    required. If $4$ people having $4$ fruits each then $2 \times 2$
>    transactions are required. $8$ people having $8$ fruits each then $3
>  \times 4$ transactions will be required.Like this for $1024$ we would
>   need a minimum of $10 \times 2^9 = 5120$

But I am not sure that I can fully construe this.Lets denote the fruits by alphabets,For two people initially we have

```
aa  bb
```

Hence,only one exchange of 'a' with 'b',will make it

```
ab  ab
```

But when when we have four people then,

```
aaaa bbbb cccc dddd
```

I tried but I could not make this to

```
abcd abcd abcd abcd
```

in only $4$ steps,could anybody show me how to do this in $4$ steps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first round do the transactions:

> aaaa + bbbb $\to$ aabb + aabb (trading aa for bb)
>
> cccc + dddd $\to$ ccdd + ccdd (trading cc for dd)

After this in the second round two pairs of people can do the transaction

> aabb + ccdd $\to$ abcd +abcd (trading ab for cd)

Four transactions total. Apply a bit of recursive thinking.

Answer (score 3):

aaaa bbbb cccc dddd ==> 1st and 2nd person exchanging two fruits

aabb aabb cccc dddd ==> 3rd and 4th person exchanging two fruits

aabb aabb ccdd ccdd ==> Person 1 gives an a and a b to person 3, and vice versa

abcd aabb abcd ccdd ==> Similar for 2 and 4

abcd abcd abcd abcd.